# Unityのビルドで複数のAndroidManifest.xmlをマージさせる方法について

Tags: android, unity3d

お世話になっております。状況としては以下のようになっております。
Unityのエディタ上でビルドする再に自動で行われるAndroidManifest.xmlのマージを
BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer()使用時でも指定できる方法はあるのでしょうか？

1.ビルドするプラットフォームはAndroid
2.Plugins/Android以下に複数のプラグインが存在し、
　各々にAndroidManifest.xmlが存在する。
3.Unityのエディタ上でビルドすると、AndroidManifest.xmlが自動的にマージされ、
　実記で実行すると、プラグインが正常に動作する。
4.Jenkinsなどの自動ビルド環境でBuildPipeline.BuildPlayer()を使用してビルドを行うと、
　プラグイン実行時にNotFoundJavaClassとエラーが出てしまう。

※どうやらバッチコマンド経由のビルドだと、「UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools:MergeManifests」という命令が
呼び出されていないようです
意図的に呼び出しできる方法はあるのでしょうか？